# Is it possible to join these both tables?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
SELECT u.*,h.*,d.* 
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN HealthDec h ON u.ID = h.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Document d On u.ID = d.UserID;
```

and:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM OHS 
WHERE Category = 'POLICIES' 
  AND ID NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT OHSID 
    FROM User_OHS 
    WHERE UserID='1' AND Type='POLICIES'
  );
```

Both queries are working fine separately as required. But I want to combine both queries to get result for each user.

[image: Table structure]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! You should **always** include your version of MySQL (and indeed all s/ware) about which you ask a question. You should also not use images for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - use dbfiddle.uk instead.  As it stands, it's not possible to join both tables (i.e. your query results) - the latter query is only a number (a count) with no field upon which to join - you'll have to include some other field in your query result (i.e. table) in it to join to the other query. Not sure why you want u.*, h.*, d.*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine them like this, as long as your subse3lect only has onbe row and 1 coumn

```
SELECT u.*,h.*,d.* ,
(SELECT count(id) FROM OHS 
WHERE Category = 'POLICIES' 
  AND ID NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT OHSID 
    FROM User_OHS 
    WHERE UserID=u.ID AND Type='POLICIES'
  )) as countr
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN HealthDec h ON u.ID = h.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Document d On u.ID = d.UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

User_OHS is a "many-to-many mapping" or "bridge" table.  It is a common pattern in databases.

```
SELECT u.this, o.that, ...
    FROM User     AS u
    JOIN User_OHS AS uo  ON uo.UserID = u.ID
    JOIN      OHS AS  o  ON uo.OHSID = o.ID
    WHERE ...
```

But it is often poorly indexed.  Advice: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Do not use Datatype `TEXT` unless the column really might be more than a few hundred characters.  What `HomePhone` needs more than perhaps 20 characters?  Ditto for `uo.Type`.  This advice helps with making useful indexes and performance in certain queries.

If you will be 'comparing' `Birthdate` to anything, make it a `DATE`, not a `VARCHAR`.  (And be sure to cleanse the value as it is inserted.)